# How to create a global array in netlogo

Tags: arrays, global-variables, netlogo

I am trying to create an array which can be accessed by all of my patches, but it seems that even though I am setting it up as a global, it is only available in the function in which I gave it a value. I have the following three segments of code in their respective places:

`globals[a]`

toward the top of my program, in my setup function I have

`set a array:from-list n-values asize [0]`

for an integer `asize` also defined in my setup function, and my go method calls a function `addtoarr` which runs the following line:

`array:set a index val`

for `index` and `val` defined earlier in that function. It might also be worth noting that this is within an `ask patches`. When I run this code I get the following error:

`Extension exception: not an array: 0
error while patch 70 91 running ARRAY:SET
  called by procedure ADDTOARR
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go-forever'`

I am very confused by this error, because it seems to me that I defined `a` as an array, but Netlogo differs in that opinion. Does netlogo not support global arrays? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must be running `go` before running `setup`.  The error says that the global `a` still has its default value of `0`.